# Which is better for creative web development?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dreamweaver

So my question to you is which is better for web development, Dreamweaver cs6 or Microsoft visual studio 2012? I am curious to see if there are major advantages to one or the other? Or if there are small things that end up being a pain in the ass because you have to keep dealing with them throughout the development cycle? Don't hold back! I want the truth!

Comment: Dreamweaver is the best for creative web development since Adobe is all about creativeness. Unlike all those other companies that are all about coding.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an open source IDE like Aptana or Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to choose between mentioned two , I would choose Microsoft visual studio 2012 . I think Microsoft visual studio 2012 is way more powerful and gives you flexibility to integrate with other essential web development components.

In other words , Microsoft visual studio 2012 can do everything dream weaver  can offer(I think ) , but not vice versa .